# How to concatenate DateParts in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I really need a help from Database ninjas.

I have the following piece of code:

```
SELECT DATEPART(hh, BeginMinute) AS Intervalo, SUM(Qtde) AS Total
  FROM tr_CustomerCount
WHERE BeginMinute > '5/22/2013 00:00:00 AM' AND BeginMinute < '6/22/2013 12:00:00 AM'
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, BeginMinute)
```

Actually it just returns the Hour (HH) but I wanna show the HOUR and MINUTE together separated by " : " such '12:00' its can be a String, no worries.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already have `DATEPART(hh, BeginMinute)` for the hours, have you looked at the different arguments that `DATEPART` accepts?

Comment: Yup sure, but I don't know how to agrupate it! I need just one member, got it? Such hh:mm.

Cause I cannot insert another parameter such 'minute'. Its only allows one two parameters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with style 114 (section `Date and Time Styles`):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 114);
```

or, starting from SQL Server 2012 you can use [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)  ([demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4245)):

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE() , 'hh:mm');
```

Comment: +1 most elegant method... I SQL fiddled [`here`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a0f6/3) :)

Comment: Please, just a heads up..
I wanna just put 00 after the HH such "HH:00" > Always double Zero.?!

Comment: Do you want to round or to truncate the minutes ? Ex. for `15:36` the result should be `15:00` or `16:00` ?

Comment: 15:00 actually I just need the Hour, the minutes need to be 00.
Thanks! :)

Comment: @FelipeKM: if you just want the hour (and not rounded), then use the expression `right('0'+dateName(hour,BeginMinute),2)+':00'`. See my amended answer below.

Comment: SQL2012: `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'hh:\0\0') AS Sol3`

Comment: `SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 114), 4, 2, '00') AS Sol1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), GETDATE(), 114)+'00' AS Sol2`

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
DECLARE @theDate DATETIME
SET @theDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

SELECT @theDate 
PRINT (RIGHT('00' + convert(varchar(2), DATEPART(hour, @theDate)), 2) +
    ':' + RIGHT('00' + convert(varchar(2), DATEPART(minute, @theDate)), 2))
```

Explanation:

- DATEPART() returns a numeric value, so each call needs to be cast to a text/string type (varchar)
- String concatenation in T-SQL is just `'string 1' + 'string 2'`
- To pad with leading zeroes, concat your value with 2 leading zeroes, then call RIGHT() to return the right-most 2 characters from the combined string

Comment: It works fine, adding 

GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, @theDate), DATEPART(minute, @theDate).

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + rtrim(cast(DATEPART(hh, BeginMinute) as varchar)), 2) + ':' + 
       RIGHT('00' + rtrim(cast(DATEPART(mi, BeginMinute) as varchar)), 2) AS Intervalo, 
       SUM(Qtde) AS Total
FROM tr_CustomerCount
WHERE BeginMinute > '5/22/2013 00:00:00 AM' 
AND BeginMinute < '6/22/2013 12:00:00 AM'
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, BeginMinute), DATEPART(mi, BeginMinute)
```

[`Click here to see it in action at SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a0f6/2)

Answer (score 1):

This is all awfully complicated for something trivial. Why don't you simply try:

```
left(convert(varchar,current_timestamp,108),5)
```

which converts a datetime value to string represention of hours and minutes on a 24 hour clock, so a time of, say, 2:37 PM is converted to the string value `14:37`.

Once you have that, then...

```
select time_hhmm = left(convert(varchar,BeginMinute,108),5) , 
       total     = sum(Qtde)
from tr_CustomerCount
where BeginMinute > '5/22/2013 00:00:00 AM'
  and BeginMinute < '6/22/2013 12:00:00 AM'
group by left(convert(varchar,BeginMinute,108),5)
```

Much easier on the eyes.

Amended to reflect showing only HH:00 per OP's comment:

```
select time_hhmm = right( '0'+datename(hour,BeginMinute) , 2 ) + ':00 , 
       total     = sum(Qtde)
from tr_CustomerCount
where BeginMinute > '5/22/2013 00:00:00 AM'
  and BeginMinute < '6/22/2013 12:00:00 AM'
group by datename(hour,BeginMinute)
```